# How do I subtract a word from the output in bash

Tags: bash

I made a simple bash script to convert movies from .avi to .mp4 but now I want to do two more things.

1. Have the output file have only *.mp4 rather than *.avi.mp4
2. Delete the old file after the conversion is completed.

Here is my script.

```
#!/bin/bash


avconv -i "$1" -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -sn -crf 24 "$1".mp4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You should do `${1%.avi}.mp4`, where we tell bash to print the contents of `$1` with the `.avi` suffix removed, and then append the `.mp4` suffix.
2. I would suggest running `aconv ... && rm "$1"`, in order to only delete if conversion succeeds, because the `&&` operator only executes the command that follows it if the previous command succeeds.

Final version:

```
#!/bin/bash

avconv -i "$1" -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -sn -crf 24 "${1%.avi}.mp4" && rm "$1"
```

Hope this helps =)

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
avconv -i "$1" -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -sn -crf 24 "${1/.avi/.mp4}" && rm "$1"
```

#### UPDATE

In response to the comment, the syntax for search and replace is:

```
${1/oldstring/newstring}
```

So, you can use it any way you want.

Comment: Thank you very much.  If I had a file that was a *.mkv and I wanted to subtract that, would I then do this? 'avconv -i "$1" -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -sn -crf 24 "${1/.avi/.mkv}.mp4" && rm "$1"'